# Johnson Moments distribution in Python

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, distribution

The Johnson Moments distribution, whose algorithm was published in 1976, is implemented in

- an [Excel add-on](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KToA-FCIU3w) called @Risk or `theorisk`
- an [R package](https://rdrr.io/cran/SuppDists/man/Johnson.html) called `SuppDists`
- a [Matlab toolbox](https://viewer.mathworks.com/?viewer=plain_code&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mathworks.com%2Fmatlabcentral%2Fmlc-downloads%2Fdownloads%2Fsubmissions%2F46123%2Fversions%2F6%2Fcontents%2FJohnson_Curve%2Ff_johnson_M.m&embed=web) called Johnson Curve Toolbox

In Scipy, there is no implementation of it, only the Johnson[-SU](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.johnsonsu.html#scipy.stats.johnsonsu) and [-SB](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.johnsonsb.html#scipy.stats.johnsonsb) distributions, which are not the same as the Johnson Moments distribution. Is there another python library, or how can it be implemented in Python?

> [Hill, I. D, R. Hill, and R. L. Holder. 1976](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=Hill%2C%20I.%20D%2C%20R.%20Hill%2C%20and%20R.%20L.%20Holder.%201976.%20Algorithm%20AS99%3A%20Fitting%20Johnson%20curves%20by%20moments.%20Applied%20Statistics%2025%20%282%29%3A%20180%2D%2D189.). Algorithm AS99: Fitting
> Johnson curves by moments. Applied Statistics 25 (2): 180--189

Comment: Not sure what  Johnson Moments distribution is. In **R** package you provided there are Johnson SU, SB, normal and lognormal, and nothing else.

Comment: See the matlab code I added which cites the Hill paper? that is the Johnson moments distribution, `f_johnson_M`. The R package documentation on the other hand states that the parameters *"may also be estimated from the moments. Applied Statistics algorithm 99, due to Hill, Hill, and Holder (1976) has been translated into C for this implementation."*

Comment: If you even have a paper which describes the algorithm, is it not straightforward to translate the algorithm to Python code?

Comment: you saw how long the Matlab code is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem in a side project I'm currently working, and I found a solution that works quite well.

First off, I suggest you read the [Applied Statistics article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2346692?read-now=1&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) where the algorithm was first published.  You'll need to sign up for a free account, but then you get 100 free articles per month.  The reason I suggest this is, based on your description, I get the feeling you may have misunderstood what the algorithm does.  You mention the "Johnson Moments distribution" which isn't a thing.  The algorithm described in that article (same as you mention in your post) describes a function named
JNSN that takes mean, stdDev, skewness and kurtosis as inputs, and returns an estimated Johnson distribution type (Su, Sb, Normal or Exponential) plus the 4 parameters needed for the distribution (γ, δ, β and λ).  These four parameters needed are described in the literature about the Johnson distributions and are named gamma, beta, sigma and lam respectively (though in the code he refers to the last 2 as XLAM and XI, and has them in the opposite order in his function signatures).

Given the output "itype", you can choose to instantiate either a normal curve, exponential curve, [Johnson-SU](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.johnsonsu.html#scipy.stats.johnsonsu) or [Johnson-SB](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.johnsonsb.html) via SciPy.  When you do this, beta and gamma correspond to SciPy's "a" and "b" parameters, whereas sigma and lam correspond to the "location" and "scale" parameters.  You can test this by pulling the Mean, StdDev, Skewness and Kurtosis from the SciPy distribution you instantiated and checking to see that they match the inputs you passed to the JNSN function.

Now for the python implementation... There isn't one.  The code there is fortran.  I tried translating that to Python but had too many bugs in my translation.  Also, the speed of the translated code was terrible.  So, i abandoned the idea of translating the code and instead used [numpy's excellent F2PY module](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/f2py/) to compile the [fortran source code](http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/apstat/99) into a machine language python plugin.

Note: http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/apstat has the source code to a bunch of other fortran modules as well.
Final Note: The original source code used 4 byte floating numbers.  I updated that directly in the fortran code, then used `f2py -h ...` command to generate, then tweak the signatures for python.

Comment: You're right, I realized after making this post that the Hill et al (1976) algorithm is meant to additionally identify one of the 4 (or 6) Johnson distributions as best fit, not just SU, while dealing with overlapping parameter configurations between them. would you happen to have a finished translation of their algorithm in python, or the closest thing to the (non-existent) Johnson moments distribution? Manually mapping SU parameters to target moments is guesswork https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65567759/why-doesnt-johnson-su-distribution-give-positive-skewness-in-scipy-stats

Comment: As I mentioned above, I abandoned the idea of translating.  Instead, I took the fortran source code (linked above) and compiled it to a python plugin using F2PY (also linked above).  I suggest you do the same.

Comment: One more thing.  There algorithm returns "ITYPE" values from 1 to 5, where 1 is lognormal, 2 is Su, 3 is Sb, 4 is Normal and 5 is completely worthless.  if you get an ITYPE of 5, you're kinda stuck.  The worst part is that sometimes the algorithm fails to converge on Sb, so it chooses to return either an ITYPE of 1 or ITYPE 5.  Neither is very useful in these situations, so be sure to watch the IFAULT parameter returned by the JNSN function closely!

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provided a couple of examples of how you used the F2PY-made module to get the parameters for given moments.

Comment: Additionally, you say that 'beta and gamma correspond to SciPy's "a" and "b" parameters'. Shouldn't it be delta instead of beta?