# Why doesn't Johnson-SU distribution give positive skewness in scipy.stats?

Tags: python, statistics, skew, probability-distribution, scipy.stats

The code below maps the statistical moments (mean, variance, skewness, excess kurtosis) generated by corresponding parameters (`a`, `b`, `loc`, `scale`) of the [Johnson-SU distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_SU-distribution) (`johnsonsu`).

For the range of loop values specified in my code below, no parameter configuration results in positive skewness, only negative skewness, even though it should be possible to parameterize the Johnson-SU distribution to be positively-skewed.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import johnsonsu

moments = ['mu','sd','sk','ku']
X = []
for a in np.arange(0.5,5,.5):
    for b in np.arange(0.5,5,.5):
        for c in np.arange(-0.5,0.5,.25): #loc
            for d in [1]: #scale
                mvsk = johnsonsu.stats(a,b,c,d,moments='mvsk')
                mvsk = [mvsk[i].tolist() for i in range(len(mvsk))]
                X.append([a,b,c,d]+mvsk)
X = pd.DataFrame(np.asarray(X), columns=['a','b','c','d']+moments)   

for m in moments:
    print(m, X[[m]].min().round(3).values[0], X[[m]].max().round(3).values[0])
```

The min and max moments printed are:

```
mu -29937.57 0.136
sd 0.053 48036174150.987
sk -414.36 -0.078
ku 0.221 41173.869
```

What would be better ranges to explore for the `a`, `b`, `loc` and `scale` parameters than what I have specified below? The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.johnsonsu.html) only says `a` and `b` must be positive, nothing about what `loc` and `scale` must be limited to.

Comment: The essence of the question appears statistical rather than programing-related, so I think it should be moved to Cross Validated SE. Regarding the question itself, I guess you could obtain opposite skewness by putting a minus in front of the generated values. This does not tell what parameters `a` and `b` that would correspond to, though. But perhaps you could reverse-engineer them then?

Comment: the Johnson SU distribution should generate positive skewness so this is a programming question given that no one has mapped the parameters to corresponding moments. The `johnsonsu` function is the only way to do this mapping, there is nothing to discuss about statistical theory that wasn't already discussed (without resolution) in the existing Cross val post

Comment: You are asking what parameter combination gives positive skewness, not how to implement that (you have implemented it already.) Thus, the statistical question is clearly present. But what is the programming question, if there indeed is one? Could you also provide a link to the Cross Validated post you are referencing?

Comment: what parameter combination gives a positive skewness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On looking at the Wikipedia article and the source code, it looks to me like the parameter `a` can change the skewness. Try negative values of `a`. The documentation says `a` must be greater than zero, but on glancing at the formulas and the code, that appears to be a bug in the documentation, and actually `a` can be less than or equal to zero.

I've tried your program above, replacing the range for `a` with `np.arange(-2.5, 2.5, .5)`. It runs without error (although there are warnings about imprecision in the results, which are also present in the original) and reports:

```
mu -202.147 548.542
sd 0.052 16114617.207
sk -414.352 402.646
ku 0.213 41173.867
```

PS. I've reported this as a bug to the Scipy project: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/13353

Comment: The documentation says "for all x, a, b > 0, ...".  That could be interpreted as implying that `a > 0`, but I don't think that was the intent.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. Anyway it wouldn't hurt to clarify it.

Comment: @RobertDodier thanks and good catch. not sure if you know anything regarding this related question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/502648/moments-table-for-johnson-su-distribution-reference-request